# System Image restore crashes consistently while trying to access external media

Tags: windows-7, mac, crash, system-restore

I am trying to restore a *System Image* from an external drive to the only disk drive mounted in a brand new [Mac Pro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Pro). Whenever I try to launch the *System Image Restore*, I get a crash in **BMRUI** with an access violation (instruction at address 0xff0db494 referenced memory at 0x00000000). How could I get the *System Image Restore* to work?

The crash happens after I click *Next* in the first restore dialog, while the *Scanning for system image disk* message is displayed. My external drive has two partitions on it:

1. A 200 MB EFI System Partition.
2. A 1397 GB NTFS Data Partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **EFI System Partition** on the backup disk was somehow confusing Windows 7 and causing it to crash. I had to remove the EFI System Partition (basically I wiped the backup disk) and create a new backup, then move to the new machine, and restore again. The System Image restore no longer crashed once I was asking it to read the system image from an attached disk with only one partition.

To get rid of the *EFI System Partition*, the easiest is to use the [diskpart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskpart) program:

1. Launch an elevated CMD (open the Windows menu, type CMD and press Shift-Ctrl-RETURN).
2. Type `diskpart`
3. Type `list disk` and find which disk is the one you need to wipe clean.
4. Type `select disk nnn` where *nnn* is the disk number.
5. Make sure it is the right disk by doing a `list partition` and check that it has an *EFI System Partition* on it.
6. Type `clean`. This will wipe the whole disk -- all your data will be lost.
7. Type `exit` to exit `diskpart`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Windows Server 2008 R2. Apparently a bug in bmrui.exe. For me it worked when I assigned a drive letter to the backup volume. I didn't have one assigned before since it wasn't needed by the backup application.

Answer (score 0):

Though in this question the drive size is fine, for others this may be caused by the backup drive being too large. Windows 7, SBS2011, Windows Server 2008 and 2008R2 do not support drives larger than 2TB.

Windows Server 2012 and 2016 do support 4TB backup drives.

Answer (score -2):

Easy solution:

get backup of "system state" and drives (C: or more)

*!no recovery

!no efi drive*

for Example: 
[image]

It should work great