# How to restore (or setup) Windows 7 on a brand new MacPro?

Tags: windows-7, mac, installation, boot, restore

While trying to restore Windows 7 from a *System Image* on a brand-new MacPro (see also [System Image restore crashes consistently while trying to access external media](https://superuser.com/questions/298823/system-image-restore-crashes-consistently-while-trying-to-access-external-media)), I came across several blocking issues:

1. Windows 7 is not able to restore the *System Image* to the disk found in the MacPro; it does not recognize the system on it and says that Windows version I am trying to restore is incompatible.

   To get around this issue, I removed all partitions from the hard disk.
2. Windows 7 displays an error while trying to restore the *System Image* on my now blank disk. Maybe it was not *blank enough*, who knows?

   To get around this issue, I started a Windows 7 install on the hard disk. After that, I was successfully able to restore the *System Image* on it.
3. The MacPro won't boot from the hard disk without having to press `Alt` at restart and selecting manually the boot disk.

How can I make sure that the MacPro boots from the disk in its first slot, now that it is a Windows 7 disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to first install Mac OS X on the MacPro, and then run the `Boot Camp` utility to start installing `Windows 7` and reboot. From the Windows 7 Setup, I can then launch the **System Image Restore** and it will from now on boot correctly on the hard disk specified in `Boot Camp`.